# StanfordNLP to detect compound entities with prepositions

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, named-entity-recognition

Basically, in the sentence:

```
<Lord of the bracelets> is a fantasy movie.
```

I would like to detect the compound `Lord of the bracelets` as one entity (that could be linked in the entitylink annotator as well). This means detecting structures with POS tags of a form like `NNP` `DT` `NNP` or `NN` `IN` `DT` `NNP`.

Is this possible with CoreNLP?

My current setup doesn't detect them, and I couldn't find a way to do it.

```java
  public NamedEntityRecognition() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,entitylink");
    props.setProperty("tokenize.options", "untokenizable=noneDelete");

    pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
  }


  public CoreDocument recogniseEntities(String text) {
    CoreDocument doc = new CoreDocument(text);
    pipeline.annotate(doc);
    return doc;
  }
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While @StanfordNLPHelp's answer was helpful, I thought I would add some more details into what my final solution was.

## Option 1:

Add a [*TokensRegex* annotator](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/tokensregex.html) as pointed out by the previous answer. This adds a more customisable annotator to the pipeline, and you can specify your own rules in a text file.

This is what my rules file (extended_ner.rules) looks like:

```
# these Java classes will be used by the rules
ner = { type: "CLASS", value: "edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$NamedEntityTagAnnotation" }
tokens = { type: "CLASS", value: "edu.stanford.nlp.ling.CoreAnnotations$TokensAnnotation" }

# rule for recognizing compound names
{ ruleType: "tokens", pattern: ([{tag:"NN"}] [{tag:"IN"}] [{tag:"DT"}] [{tag:"NNP"}]), action: Annotate($0, ner, "COMPOUND"), result: "COMPOUND_RESULT" }
```

You can see a breakdown of the rules sintax [here](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/tokensregex.html#tokens-rules-patterns).

**Note:** The TokensRegex annotator *must* be added after the ner annotator. Otherwise, the results will be overwritten.

This is what the Java code would look like:

```java
 public NamedEntityRecognition() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,tokensregex,entitylink");
    props.setProperty("tokensregex.rules", "extended_ner.rules");
    props.setProperty("tokenize.options", "untokenizable=noneDelete");

    pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
  }
```

## Option 2 (Chosen one)

Instead of adding another annotator, the rules file can be sent to the ner annotator via de `"ner.additional.tokensregex.rules"` property. [Here](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/ner.html#additional-tokensregex-rules) are the docs.

I chose this option because it seems simpler, and adding another annotator to the pipeline seemed a bit overdone for my case.

The rules file is exactly the same as in option 1, the java code now is:

```java
 public NamedEntityRecognition() {
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.setProperty("annotators", "tokenize,ssplit,pos,lemma,ner,entitylink");
    props.setProperty("ner.additional.tokensregex.rules", "extended_ner.rules");

    props.setProperty("tokenize.options", "untokenizable=noneDelete");

    pipeline = new StanfordCoreNLP(props);
  }
```

**Note:** For this to work, the property `"ner.applyFineGrained"` must be true (default value).

Comment: Note that these rules will be case sensitive, unless explicitly stated in the rules file.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with TokensRegex, (possibly RegexNER, though I don't think so).  You can specify in a rule you want to mark certain part-of-speech tag patterns as an entity.

The full description of TokensRegex is provided here:

https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/tokensregex.html

Comment: Great, thanks! But will these patterns potentially be detected by NER and the entitylink annotator?

Comment: Yes you can integrate this with the ner annotator.  Please see the documentation for the ner annotator: https://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/ner.html